# Showing every element in an IEnumerable HtmlElement collection

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable

I have a collection: `IEnumerable<HtmlElement> propertyElements`.

I'd like to enumerate this collection with a `foreach` loop and see each HtmlElement contained therein.

So far, my code looks like this:

```
private static void PrintObject(IEnumerable<HtmlElement> propertyElements)
{
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
    foreach (HtmlElement element in propertyElements)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element.ToString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
}
```

My output, though, looks like this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What part of the html element do you want to see?

Comment: Like if it's a 'div' or an 'img' or other Html element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Bo pointed out you could do something like this

```
private static void PrintObject(IEnumerable<HtmlElement> propertyElements)
{
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
    foreach (HtmlElement element in propertyElements)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element.OuterHtml);
        //or
        Console.WriteLine(element.Name);
        //or
        Console.WriteLine(element.InnerHtml);
        //or
        Console.WriteLine(element.TagName);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to print a property of each element.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement(v=vs.110).aspx

Use something like InnerHtml/InnerText or OuterHtml/OuterText

If you want the element type, use TagName

```
Console.WriteLine(element.TagName);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.tagname(v=vs.110).aspx